# What is the meaning of the nine dots?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I' am wondering what those nine dots in the ROS logo mean.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187963/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-nine-dots?/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-27

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-28**:
One of those dots has become a question mark now.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-28**:
This is just a slightly changed logo for a special use in ROSAnswers, I think that this is pretty obvious...

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
Is this a karma question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The story that I know is that it's a mounting hole pattern.  If you look at the PR2 robot, there are mounting plates on the sides of the "neck" and on the top of the head, where you can bolt on extra hardware.  This makes the robot more versatile, since you can add stuff to it.  The ROS pattern is meant to be a visualization of these mounting holes, with the implication that ROS is also versatile, and that you can add extra stuff onto it.

Someone from the early Willow Garage days might be able to confirm this or, alternatively, tell me that I'm making things up.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3